# Signalr method not invoked on server

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

I have two methods on server to be invoked, almost identical, simply only one of them (SubscribeToWatchlist) is getting fired on server side once invoked. UnsubscribeFromWatchlist is not.

> ASP.NET Core 8

```
 public async Task SubscribeToWatchlist(int watchlistType)
  {
      int userId = int.Parse(Context.User.Identity.Name);
      string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;


      if (_watchlistSubscriptions.TryAdd(Context.ConnectionId + watchlistType, new CancellationTokenSource()))
      {
          await _realtimeService.MonitorWatchlist(watchlistType, userId, connectionId, _watchlistSubscriptions[Context.ConnectionId + watchlistType].Token);
      }
  }

  public void UnsubscribeFromWatchlist(int watchlistType)
  {
      int userId = int.Parse(Context.User.Identity.Name);
      string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

      //await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "watchlist-" + watchlistType);

      if (_watchlistSubscriptions.TryRemove(Context.ConnectionId + watchlistType, out var cts))
      {
          _realtimeService.StopMonitoringWatchlist(watchlistType, userId, connectionId, cts.Token);
          cts.Cancel();
          cts.Dispose();
      }
  }
```

> Javascript

```
  async subscribeToWatchlist() {
    await this.connection.invoke("SubscribeToWatchlist", 1);
  },

  async unsubscribeFromWatchlist() {
    await this.connection.invoke("UnsubscribeFromWatchlist", 1);
  },
```

When triggering the Unsubscribe method the Dev tools on chrome shows this

{"arguments":[1],"invocationId":"7","target":"UnsubscribeFromWatchlist","type":1}{"type":7}

Which means connection, client side work is all good.

The contents of both methods and the way to invoke them is almost identical. Any idea why the  UnsubscribeFromWatchlist is not getting hit (VS breakpoints and Debug.Writeline do not trigger)?

Answer (score 1):

> The contents of both methods and the way to invoke them is almost
> identical. Any idea why the UnsubscribeFromWatchlist is not getting
> hit (VS breakpoints and Debug.Writeline do not trigger)?

Well, according to your scenario, description along with the shared code snippet, at the very first look, I have observed that, your both client-side that is Javascript functions are asynchronous those are, `subscribeToWatchlist` and `unsubscribeFromWatchlist` which looks good.

According to the functions definition and signature, your server side methods also should capable of handleing asynchronous request.

However, in my investigations, I found your `UnsubscribeFromWatchlist` is synchronous. As you may know, synchronous hub methods can block the main JavaScript thread because its not align with the asynchronous call, preventing the browser from responding to user interactions and rendering updates until the method completes. This can lead to break the execution. As a result, method may exit execution before its getting hit.

Like your other method, try to make the `UnsubscribeFromWatchlist` method as asynchronous. You could refactor as following:

```
public async Task UnsubscribeFromWatchlist(int watchlistType)
{
    int userId = int.Parse(Context.User.Identity.Name);
    string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

    if (_watchlistSubscriptions.TryRemove(connectionId + watchlistType, out var cts))
    {
        await _realtimeService.StopMonitoringWatchlist(watchlistType, userId, connectionId, cts.Token);
        cts.Cancel();
        cts.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In addition, double-check that both server-side methods have the exact same name and parameter types as their client-side counterparts. Even minor differences (e.g., casing, argument order) can prevent invocation. Because, your method parameters is `int` so make sure in your browser network trace, that its sending `int` value not the `"1"`. Because int javascript you often get this issue.

Last but not least, make sure, your [`HubClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#cross-origin-connections-cors) has been [injected or configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#cross-origin-connections-cors) accordingly within your [program.cs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#cross-origin-connections-cors) file.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-the-client), regarding how you can [call the hub method from your javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-hub-methods-from-the-client) client.